# Get Quill editor instance from HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, quill

Assuming I created an editor instance for a certain element, e.g. via `const editor = new Quill('#editor', {...some options});`

Now, I would like to get this editor instance when only having the element available, e.g. something like `const editor = Quill.existingEditorFromElement('#editor');`

The reason is that I am building a component that can be plugged into existing websites that enhances their editors, and I need a way to get their editor instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673629/quill-text-editor-how-to-use-instances-after-creating-with-jquery

Answer (score 3):

According to [Quill API Documentation](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#find-experimental) you can get the editor instance by getting the DOM element by its ID (or classname or tagname...), and inserting it inside the find function.

Example:

```
var div = document.getElementById('editor');
var quill_instance = Quill.find(div);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using `Quill.find('#editor');`, see https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#find-experimental